# Objective-C: How to use AVPictureInPictureController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avplayer, avplayerlayer, picture-in-picture

I am trying to set up picture in picture for my iPad app and I have a custom video player so I am following the sample code from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationPiPPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html

I am implementing this in Objective-C and the second line of code below gives the error that "Property isPictureInPictureSupported not found on object of type AVPictureInPictureController.

```
AVPictureInPictureController *controller = [[AVPictureInPictureController alloc]init];

if (controller.isPictureInPictureSupported) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`isPictureInPictureSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller/1614693-ispictureinpicturesupported?language=objc) is a *class method* on `AVPictureInPictureController`, not an instance property. So you call it like this:

```
if ([AVPictureInPictureController isPictureInPictureSupported]) {
```